# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException (JDBC)

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   gui.CataloguePanel.(CataloguePanel.java)

I'm trying to initialize a `BookQuery` object in `CataloguePanel` and call `getBookList()`

CataloguePanel.java

```
package gui;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import backend.Book;
import backend.BookQuery;

// Catalog panel. Shows the library titles' information and allows users to place their orders.
public class CataloguePanel extends JPanel implements GBPanel {

    BookQuery bQuery;
    ArrayList<Book> bookList = bQuery.getBookList(); // Here's where the error occurred

}
```

**EDIT:** http://www.reactionface.info/sites/default/files/imagecache/Node_Page/images/1314029819767.png

Comment: something is null. read the exception and fix it!

Comment: Thanks capt. Obvious.

Comment: The whole thing is obvious. This trivial error has nothing to do with MySQL or JDBC whatsoever. You are really expected to be able to fix `NullPointerExceptions` by yourself. There's nothing mysterious about your 14 lines of code, which includes 5 blank lines and a comment line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
BookQuery bQuery;
ArrayList<Book> bookList = bQuery.getBookList();
```

`bQuery` is not initialized, so it is similer like `null.getBookList()` which must produce `NullPointerException`. Either you initialize `bQuery`. like -

```
BookQuery bQuery= new BookQuery();
```

Or make the `getBookList()` method `static` and call the method like -

```
ArrayList<Book> bookList = BookQuery.getBookList();
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to instantiate the bookQuery

```
 BookQuery bQuery= new BookQuery();
```

Comment: Oh god... How could I missed out that? Geez. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you need to do  `BookQuery bQuery = new BookQuery();`

Answer (score 0):

`bQuery` is not initialized and therefore is `null`. This produces NPE. 
You have to initialize it: 
`BookQuery bQuery= new BookQuery();`

(as it was mentioned by @Daniel Robertus) +1